# Problem regarding google cloud bucket access permission

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I am working on a colab project with google cloud bucket. At first, I use my own Gmail account A, but I notice that I need a google service account for some operations. So I activate a service account B and I successfully log in with this service account.

But here are still a permission error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: Error executing an HTTP request: HTTP response code 403 with body '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "gmailaccountA@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "gmailaccountA@gmail.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I double check and run the `"gcloud auth list"`, I get two active accounts, one is my gmail account A and one is my service account B. How could I make sure I am using the service account?

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the account you want to use you can first list them to check the ones available using

```
gcloud auth list
```

and to set the chosen one use:

```
gcloud config set account ACCOUNT
```

You can read more about the [`gcloud config set`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set) command and its properties [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/configurations#AVAILABLE-PROPERTIES)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did as you said to set account and run "gcloud init" to log on to the service account. But this error still exists.

Comment: There's no need to run gcloud init after you set the account.

Comment: Hi there, I followed your instruction, and right now only one service account is active. The error 403 is gone but I got a new error 401: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Do you know what the reason is? really appreciate.